# DIV Slide to the left, stay on top and reduce to a smaller width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is original idea, helped by @Tom RNS: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/5/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#moving").click(function () {
          $("#moving").toggleClass("left");
        });
    });
```

This works fine... But, I need to refine it a little bit:

Originally the DIVs remain 50% of width, but when the sliding DIV is clicked I need it to be reduced to a third of the width, and make the revealed right DIV two thirds...

Is that possible? and how? Thank you!

Comment: Have you tryed jquery .animate() ? http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation

Comment: Do you still want it to slide besides reducing its width?

Comment: Yeah, I need it to slide back when clicked again... kind of like toggle...

Comment: Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/6/)?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, something like that, but it has to move to the left, like the original, and widen the right side div...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean like this ?

https://jsfiddle.net/m46wLz0n/

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left" >
        <p>Left side</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>Right side</p>
    </div>
    <div id="moving">
        <p>Moving div</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
}
#left{
    background-color: red;
    width:50%;
    height:150px;
    float: left;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
#left.smallerLeft{
     width:33.33%;    
}
#right{
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    height:150px;
    float: left;
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
#right.biggerRight{
    width:66.66%;
}
#moving{
    background-color: blue;
    width:50%;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s; /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
#moving.left{
    left:0;
    width:33.33%;
}
```

Javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#moving").click(function(){
        $("#moving").toggleClass("left");
        $("#right").toggleClass("biggerRight");
        $("#left").toggleClass("smallerLeft");
     });
  });
```

Comment: wow yes, thats right. Now I ll try to implement it into my code. Thank you very much!!

Comment: You LITERALLY copied Matteo Rubini's answer

Answer (score 2):

Just a bit tricky but it works..

https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/7/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#moving").click(function(){
      $("#left").toggleClass("left");
      $("#moving").toggleClass("left");
      $("#right").toggleClass("left");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing this by adding a class to the *right* element, too.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#moving").click(function(){
      $("#moving").toggleClass("left");
       $("#right").toggleClass("right");
   });
});
```

CSS:

```
#moving.left{
    left:0;
    width: 33.33%;
}
#right.right{
    width: 66.66%;
    margin-left: -16.66%;
}
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/mq2c2129/14/